# Ionic 3 SQLite - database as private member variable vs. creating a new database on every query?

Tags: angular, sqlite, typescript, ionic3, ionic-native

I have a simple question - would it be better in Ionic 3 to have the opened database in a private member variable of a database provider class, or to call `create` every time the database is queried?

I.e. **this**...

```
private db: SQLiteObject;

constructor() {
  this.sqlite.create(...)
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    this.db = db;
  })
}

queryMethod() {
  db.executeSql(sql, {});
}
```

...or **this**?

```
constructor() {

}

queryMethod() {
  this.sqlite.create(...)
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql(sql, {});
  });
}
```

I do see a problem with the first approach, as there's a small probability that the database might not have been created before it's accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Since this is `Promise` you always need to use the `2nd` option.Then you will not have any issues. That means you need to execute the query after resolving the promise.

*Follow below pattern always:*

```
queryMethod() {
  this.sqlite.create(...)
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql(sql, {});
  });
}
```